# Class has no member named (using ESP32 create web server)

Tags: c++, webserver, esp32, platformio

I use **PlatformIO** (VS code) to program the engine control via web server using ESP32.
I have 2 projects and i am looking for a way to combine them so that only control on a single interface and HTTP address is required.

Now that I use the following libraries.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <ESP32Servo.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <WebServer.h>
#include <ESPmDNS.h>
```

Initially, I instantiate an object named **server** that runs on port 80.

```
WiFiServer server(80);
```

I got 16 errors " **'class ...' has no member named '...'** " so I renamed my object accordingly and only got 1 error left

```
WebServer server(80);
```

I get the error **'class WebServer' has no member named 'available'** In line

```
void loop(){
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
```

The fact that one project uses **"WiFiServer server(80);"** and the other uses **"WebServer server(80);"**. When I combine them, there will be conflicts between the components. At least I improved and only got 1 error

Is there a way for me to run both classes using port 80 ?

My code is quite long so I can't post it here, I have read many solutions but not solve my problem I cant search for the right problem.

Comment: Arduino uses a C++ variant, not C.

Comment: WiFiServer has available(), not WebServer. for use of WebServer see the examples of the WebServer library

Comment: Does the `WebServer` class have a function called `available`?

Comment: WebServer class doesn't have a function called available. But WiFiServer has a function called available. and that function is necessary for my code. If I use WiFiServer there are 16 functions that cannot be used. So I need help.

Comment: You need documentation. Possibly these two: [WifiServer](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/WiFi/src/WiFiServer.h) and [WebServer](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/WebServer/src/WebServer.h). Next time just google "arduino esp32 <name of class>" and you'll find it yourself.

Comment: Is there a way for me to run both classes using port 80 ?